# Which is the main verb in the bolded sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, paraphrasing

> **If what happens in your experience is inside your mind in a way in which what happens in your brain is not**, it looks as though your experiences and other mental states can't just be physical states of your brain.

[Thomas Nagel, What does it all mean, p30]

I have some questions to ask

1. Which is the main verb in the **bolded sentence**?
2. Is my rewrite correct!? Does my rewrite have the same meaning as the **bolded sentence**?

> "If your perceptions are experienced within consciousness, and not the way the processes in your brain are going on"

Thank you!

Comment: Well evidently clarity wasn't a priority in this particular sentence.  The meaning is a little convoluted, but the main verb is the first "is".

Answer (score 1):

The bolded passage is not a sentence, but a clause governed by the "if". But the verb in that clause is ***is** (inside your mind)*, and I agree more or less with your interpretation.

But the *is not* is saying something a little stronger than your paraphrase: it says that what happens in your brain is not in your mind.

Comment: So, what does "in a way" mean!?

Comment: _In a way_ is a bit vague. Something like "in a sense" or "in a manner", or even "to a degree".

Comment: "happens in a way"
or
"is inside your mind in a way"?

Thanks!

Comment: "is inside your mind in a way which ... "

Comment: I apologize for bothering you again, after reading it several times, I think of three explanations for the if clause:



- First, the experiences happen in the mind is not the same as what happens in the brain.
and
- Second, both what happens in your experience and what happens in your brain are inside your mind, but in a different way
and
- Third, what happens in your experience is inside your mind in a way, and what happens in your brain is not that way.

Which is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: As I said, it's not completely clear. But I read it that the _way_ means "a way of describing, or theorising about, or interpreting" - it's about the author's description, not about some aspect of what is  being described. So I would paraphrase it as something more like _If it is more accurate or valid to describe your experience as being something in your mind than to describe it as being something in your brain_.